# How to execute IF EXISTS UPDATE ELSE INSERT syntax in SSMS 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, ssms, sql-insert

IF EXISTS THEN UPDATE ELSE INSERT not executing properly in SQL Server 2008

I have been advised that a MERGE could be useful but my data seems to not be applicable for this - it tries to UPDATE records twice because there are duplicate records in the source table

```
IF EXISTS (select 1
            from SCM_Top_Up_Operational O
            join SCM_Top_Up_Rolling R ON O.String = R.string)
BEGIN

UPDATE O SET                           O.Date_Added = R.Date_Added,
                                       O.Real_Exfact = R.Real_Exfact,
                                       O.Excess_Top_Up = R.Excess_Top_Up 

                               FROM    SCM_Top_Up_Operational O JOIN SCM_Top_Up_Rolling R ON O.String = R.String
                               WHERE   O.String = R.string
                               AND     R.Date_Added > O.Date_Added;
END         

ELSE 

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO SCM_Top_Up_Operational (String,Date_Added,Real_Exfact,Article_ID,Excess_Top_Up,Plant) 
          SELECT R.String,R.Date_Added,R.Real_Exfact,R.Article_ID,R.Excess_Top_Up,R.Plant 
          FROM SCM_Top_Up_Rolling R 
          WHERE R.String NOT IN (SELECT String FROM SCM_Top_Up_Operational)
END
```

The expected result would be to UPDATE any records in the 'Operational' table with the MOST recent record added to the 'rolling' table - this is accomplished by a JOIN on the 'String' field which is unique in the 'Operational' table but is duplicated in the 'Rolling' table.  The only difference is 'Date_Added' - which is where I would UPDATE from the most recent record in the 'Rolling' table. If there is no match then move on to the INSERT statement where it would INSERT any rows that are present in the 'Rolling' table but not in the 'Operational' table.  I have researched many other threads and this syntax looks correct.

What the issue is:

If I execute the entire statement the UPDATE part works fine but the ELSE INSERT does nothing - however if I run the INSERT on its own it works fine as well.  My guess is I am missing something small in the syntax.  As mentioned I have been advised to use MERGE but due to the nature of my data - the ON statement in MERGE would find the primary key from the source table twice and returns an error.  Any ideas what I may be missing in this code?  I am fairly good with SQL but these types of statements are somewhat new to me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write this query.

```
 UPDATE 
       O 
    SET                           
       O.Date_Added = R.Date_Added,
       O.Real_Exfact = R.Real_Exfact,
       O.Excess_Top_Up = R.Excess_Top_Up 
   FROM    
       SCM_Top_Up_Operational O JOIN SCM_Top_Up_Rolling R ON O.String = R.String
   WHERE   
       O.String = R.string
       AND R.Date_Added > O.Date_Added;

   INSERT INTO SCM_Top_Up_Operational 
            (String,Date_Added,Real_Exfact,Article_ID,Excess_Top_Up,Plant) 
         SELECT 
             R.String,
             R.Date_Added,R.Real_Exfact,R.Article_ID,R.Excess_Top_Up,R.Plant 
         FROM 
             SCM_Top_Up_Rolling R 
         WHERE 
             R.String NOT IN (SELECT String FROM SCM_Top_Up_Operational)
```

Comment: I just noticed if I take out the ELSE it does exactly what I want - is there any need for the ELSE? I was looking at other SO threads and SQL blogs as a guide and they all seemed to include the ELSE statement  -  your answer is technically two queries correct?

Comment: It's not required if else condition because you want to update records at that time same criteria put in where condition. If your where condition fulfills then update rows otherwise nothing any rows updated.